# Changing the Projection of Shapefile

Tags: r, projection, shapefile, r-sp

I am trying to change or assign the projection of a Germany-Shapefile from `NA` to `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0`, but somehow it doesn't work well.

Reproducible Example:
Shapefile and other files can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqofou8dc03udh9/shapefile.zip?dl=0):

What I tried is the following:

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
projection.x <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0")
mapG <- readShapePoly("vg2500_lan.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=projection.x)
summary(mapG)
mapG <- spTransform(mapG, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
```

So, the problem is I cannot plot my observations on the map. See below

[image]
The ponits were detected using `geocode` function from `ggmap` package.
[image]
Any idea how to change the projection of the shapefile or the projection of the google coordinates would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found my mistake. The solution would be:

```
mapG <- readOGR("vg2500_lan.shp", layer="vg2500_lan")
summary(mapG)
germG <- spTransform(mapG, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(germG, axes=T)
```

And the desired output:
[image]

Comment: Your link to the data does not work anymore. Could you provide a sample with dput?